# How to generate (paint) EAN-128 barcode with ZXing in Android

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-printing, gs1-128

I'm using ZXing to paint EAN-13 barcodes in my app and now i am requested to paint EAN-128 also. I've read that EAN-13, also called GS1-128 is a descendant from Code-128, which the ZXing library supports.

The question is, if i already have the EAN-128 numeric code, and i paint it with BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 will it be correct, or are EAN-128 and Code-128 different ways of painting it?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance